# CSS spinner as full page overlay

Tags: html, css

I am wondering how to get an overlay with a centered spinner which will take up the full page length/width.

I found the following spinner online, and it looks great, but they overlay is only taking up a about 25% of the page.  I am a back-end developer, and not very strong at CSS.  What adjustments do I need to make it order to get the overlay at 100%, and `z-index` increased so that elements behind are not clickable?

```css
.spinner {
  margin: 100px auto;
  width: 50px;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 10px;
}

.spinner>div {
  z-index: 999;
  background-color: black;
  height: 100%;
  width: 6px;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-animation: sk-stretchdelay 1.2s infinite ease-in-out;
  animation: sk-stretchdelay 1.2s infinite ease-in-out;
}

.spinner .rect2 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -1.1s;
  animation-delay: -1.1s;
}

.spinner .rect3 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -1.0s;
  animation-delay: -1.0s;
}

.spinner .rect4 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.9s;
  animation-delay: -0.9s;
}

.spinner .rect5 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.8s;
  animation-delay: -0.8s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes sk-stretchdelay {
  0%,
  40%,
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.4)
  }
  20% {
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.0)
  }
}

@keyframes sk-stretchdelay {
  0%,
  40%,
  100% {
    transform: scaleY(0.4);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.4);
  }
  20% {
    transform: scaleY(1.0);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="spinner">
  <div class="rect1"></div>
  <div class="rect2"></div>
  <div class="rect3"></div>
  <div class="rect4"></div>
  <div class="rect5"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add another container to wrap your spinner:

```
<div class="loading">
  <div class="spinner">
    <div class="rect1"></div>
    <div class="rect2"></div>
    <div class="rect3"></div>
    <div class="rect4"></div>
    <div class="rect5"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

make `.loading` full width / full height and position fixed: Add z-index if necessary

```
.loading {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

center your spinner:

```
.spinner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -20px;
  margin-left: -25px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

hope that helps
[working copy](https://jsfiddle.net/2zv3LL7x/)

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to get this.

Here is one of them:

Set the position of the container to absolute, and use the vw/vh (viewport-width, viewport-height) to get the relevant position.

> To make sure the position is exactly the center I used half the width/height of the spinner itself.

```css
.spinner {
  width: 50px;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(50vw - 25px);
  top: calc(50vh - 20px);
}

.spinner>div {
  z-index: 999;
  background-color: black;
  height: 100%;
  width: 6px;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-animation: sk-stretchdelay 1.2s infinite ease-in-out;
  animation: sk-stretchdelay 1.2s infinite ease-in-out;
}

.spinner .rect2 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -1.1s;
  animation-delay: -1.1s;
}

.spinner .rect3 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -1.0s;
  animation-delay: -1.0s;
}

.spinner .rect4 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.9s;
  animation-delay: -0.9s;
}

.spinner .rect5 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.8s;
  animation-delay: -0.8s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes sk-stretchdelay {
  0%,
  40%,
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.4)
  }
  20% {
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.0)
  }
}

@keyframes sk-stretchdelay {
  0%,
  40%,
  100% {
    transform: scaleY(0.4);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.4);
  }
  20% {
    transform: scaleY(1.0);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="spinner">
  <div class="rect1"></div>
  <div class="rect2"></div>
  <div class="rect3"></div>
  <div class="rect4"></div>
  <div class="rect5"></div>
</div>
```